# Exposed filter in view should display all available values in select box

Tags: views

I added an exposed filter to my view where users can enter the desired value to filter the results accordingly. But I want to make it easier for them by changing this filter to a select box style dropdown where they can select a value out of all available values.

To make this more clear; I'm talking about a year, so each article has a field "year" and because there are many articles published in many years, I want to group all available years from all articles and show them to the user in this select box.

But I can only make this possible by adding the years in the grouped filters manually, that means each year I have to add a new option to the filter manually. And if there are articles added later which originally were published earlier than years available in the options, I probably will never cover all years in this set of static options.

So is there a way to get all years of all articles and showing them in a select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more research would have helped, I found out myself how to do this. (Though I don't know if it would work without custom code.)

I hooked into `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` inside my theme (would also work in a custom module) and altered the form like this:

```
function MYTHEME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-MYVIEWID-MYFORMID') {
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'article')->execute();
    $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $options = ['' => 'All'];

    foreach($nodes as $nid => $node) {
      $value = $node->get('field_article_year')->getString();

      if (isset($value)) {
        $options[$value] = $value;
      }
    }

    asort($options, SORT_NUMERIC);

    if (isset($form['article_year'])) {
      $form['article_year']['#type'] = 'select';
      $form['article_year']['#options'] = $options;
      $form['article_year']['#size'] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```